# Salesforce SSO delegated authentication

Tags: single-sign-on

I am new to Salesforce and trying to understand the concept of Delegated Gateway URL of Single Sign On. I understand that Salesforce will enable this feature after submitting the case and I have to configure in profile level "Is Single sign on" equals true. But under single sign on setting page -- Delegated Authentication section -- when and how to use these two settings:

1. Delegated Gateway URL
2. Force Delegated Authentication Callout

Thank you very much in advance and it will be great help if there is any small example you can share.

Comment: It would help to know what you're trying to achieve, why are you looking at delegated authentication

Comment: Thanks, I just would like to know what is the use case of Delegated Gateway URL and when to use this in single sign on?